# Java "x += y" and "x = x+y" yields different result

Tags: java, casting, bit-manipulation

I came up with two expressions to assign value from a bit operation to a variable, and noticed "x+=y" and "x=x+y" yielded different results in this case:

```
public void random () 
{
        int n =     43261596;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
        n = n + 0&1; //binary representation of n is 0
        //n += 0&1;  //result is the same as n
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
}
```

I did some research, and found the only case "x+=y" and "x=x+y" is not equivalent is when operant types are not the same, however in this case, "n" is type of `int`, and "0&1" shoud be a type of `int` (according to this question [Why does bitwise AND of two short values result in an int value in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279718/why-does-bitwise-and-of-two-short-values-result-in-an-int-value-in-java):

> Because the Java Language Specification says that the result of non-long integer arithmetic is always an int.)

So I'm wondering why it yields different results.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The difference is [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html#nutsandbolts-precedence). `+` has precedence to `&`, but `&` has precedence to `+=`. So your operations translate to this:

```
n = (n + 0) & 1; // = n & 1 = 0 (when n is even)
n += (0 & 1);    // = n + 0 = n
```

Comment: Here is an Operator Precedence for future reference [JavaOperatorPrecedenceTable](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~guvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html). Good answer, very clear and concise

Answer (score 5):

The operator & has a lower precedence than +.

What you have actually written is:

```
n = ( n + 0 ) &1;
```

I added parentheses to clarify.

Since n is an even number, the outcome of that expression is zero.

Answer (score 0):

in first case,n will **plus** 0 first and then **and** 1

```
n = n+0&1 -> n = (n + 0)&1 -> 0
n+=0&1 ->n+=(0&1)->n
```