# How produce two's complement of a Uint16?

Tags: java, binary, uint8t, uint16

I have two bytes of data. I converted each of them to Uint8 then I produced a Uint16 from them.

How I can produce two's complement of this Uint16 number?

I've tried `uInt16 = ~uInt16 + 1` but the code produces 32bit integer and I want it to stay a 16bit Integer.

```java
    byte firstByte, secondByte;
    int firstUint8, secondUint8, uInt16;
    firstByte = buffer[index];//get first byte from buffer
    secondByte = buffer[index + 1];//get second byte from buffer


    firstUint8=firstByte & 0xFF;//produce Uint8
    secondUint8 = secondByte & 0xFF;//produce Uint8

    uInt16 = 256 * firstUint8 + secondUint8;//create Uint16 from these to    Uint8

    twosComplementOfUInt16=~number+1; //produce 32 bit integer but I want int16
```

Comment: In Java an `int` is 32bit. What exactly do you expect?

Comment: `int` is 32-bit. You should use `short`.

Comment: Simplified, clarified wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is not the best programing language to work with bits. But if you want you can read the [documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Primitive_Types) to see how the number are represented in java; how to [work with bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) or you can do a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm).

**As observation the [(~ and +) returns an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279718/why-does-bitwise-and-of-two-short-values-result-in-an-int-value-in-java)**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int uint8 = 0xff;
        int uint16 = 0xffff;
        long uint32 = 0xffffffff;

        int one = 0x0001;
        int ten = 0x000A;
        int twoComplementOfTen = 0xFFF6;
        int computedTwoComplementOfTen = ~ten + one;
        int revertTwoComplementOfTen = ~twoComplementOfTen + one;

        System.out.printf("One = 0x%04X \n", one);
        System.out.printf("ten = 0x%04X \n", ten);
        System.out.printf("~ten + one = 0x%04X \n", twoComplementOfTen);
        System.out.printf("Computed ~ten + one = 0x%04X \n", computedTwoComplementOfTen);
        System.out.printf("~twoComplementOfTen + one = 0x%04X \n", revertTwoComplementOfTen);

        System.out.printf("Computed ~ten + one with uint16 mask = 0x%04X \n", uint16 & computedTwoComplementOfTen);
        System.out.printf("~twoComplementOfTen + one with uint16 mask  = 0x%04X \n", uint16 & revertTwoComplementOfTen);
    }
```

```
Output:

One = 0x0001 
Ten = 0x000A 
~ten + one = 0xFFF6 
Computed ~ten + one = 0xFFFFFFF6 
~twoComplementOfTen + one = 0xFFFF000A 
Computed ~ten + one with uint16 mask = 0xFFF6 
~twoComplementOfTen + one with uint16 mask  = 0x000A
```

Answer (score 0):

The "twos complement" of a number is obtained by negation, at least on machines that use twos-complement representation of integers, which is true for nearly all modern hardware and is true for the Java virtual machine.

```
  short x;
     ...set value of x...
  x = -x;
```

In twos-complement hardware and in the Java virtual machine, negation is equivalent to invert and add one. The following demonstrates this:

Example:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        short n = 2; n = -n;
        System.out.println(n);
        short m = 2; m = ~m + 1;
        System.out.println(m);
    }
}
```

The output from the above is identical for `m` and `n`.

If you find it necessary to use 32-bit ints for the value then you can simply mask the result to 16 bits.

```
    int uint16 = some_value;
    int compl = -uint16 & 0xffff;
```